# Analyse complexity of code (Fibonacci Series)

Tags: python, fibonacci, series

This is an iterative version of calculating Fibonacci series in python:

```
def fib_iterative(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    if n == 2:
        return [1,1]
    fib_list = [1,1]
    for i in range(0,n):
        fib_list.append(fib_list[i]+fib_list[i+1])
    return fib_list
```

This is the recursive version:

```
def fib_recursive(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib_recursive(n-1) + fib_recursive(n-2)

def fib_numbers_in_list(n):
    fibn = []
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        fibn.append(fib_recursive(x))
    return fibn
```

What is the Big-O of each?

Calls are fib_numbers_in_list(n) and fib_iterative(n) to return the first n Fibonacci numbers in a list.

Is there a way we can find a O(log n) algorithm to produce n Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: You should figure out this yourself. SO is not solving task of others.

Comment: I don't see any recursion in the second example, it looks a bit *confused* . . .

Comment: This is the code I wrote. I'm just a bit confused that when I run the second version with n = 50, the python interpreter halts.

Whereas for the first version: it gives the output asap.
Just wanted some thoughts on Big-O



@NeilSlater In the second version, the nth Fibonacci number is calculated using recursion and then the second function appends them in the list, in order.

Comment: Your `fib_recursive` calls `fib`. It should be calling itself: `return fib_recursive(n-1) + fib_recursive(n-2)`. However, this is _very_ inefficient for large `n`, due to the double recursion. Calling `fib_recursive(n)` with n=20 results in a total of 35400 calls, including the original call. For n=30, the total is 4356586, and for n=50, the total is 65902560146, which is going to take a long time.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.
There is no fib, it should be fib_recursive

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  def fib_iterative(n):
>     if n == 0:
>         return []
>     if n == 1:
>         return [1]
>     if n == 2:
>         return [1,1]
>     fib_list = [1,1]
>     for i in range(0,n):
>         fib_list.append(fib_list[i]+fib_list[i+1])
>     return fib_list
> ```

This function has one for-loop, which repeats `n` times.
This makes the function `O(n)` of time complexity.

> ```
> def fib_recursive(n):
>     if n == 1:
>         return 1
>     elif n == 2:
>         return 1
>     else:
>         return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
>
> def fib_numbers_in_list(n):
>     fibn = []
>     for x in range(1,n+1):
>         fibn.append(fib_recursive(x))
>     return fibn
> ```

I think there is a mistake calling `fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)` in the code. I assume this supposed to be `fib_recursive(n-1) + fib_recursive(n-1)`.

Let's assume `fib_recursive(n)` has `f(n)` calculations to do. Simple equation to estimate it would be `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)`. And the boundary conditions would be `f(2) = 1, f(1) = 1`. This is getting familiar with you right? Time complexity for the recursive code would end up being same as fibonacci number of the input n.

Like you might know already, a nth Fibonacci number is proportional to `(2.736) ** n`. This makes time complexity of the recursive function to `O(2.736 ** n)`. (If you want more information about it, visit http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html)

Well, we are not done yet. We have to multiply it by `n` since you wish to know all the Fibonacci numbers from `1` to `n`. So the generous calculation would make the answer `O(n * 2.736 ** n)`

Answer (score 0):

You may look at the big O notation for various python operations here to estimate the time complexity:
[TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

And here's an example:

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287123/python-complexity-run-time)